# Using python to add random Matrices with Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, random

So I need to add random matrices in python. I have this code to generate a random matrix:

```
import numpy as np 
import random

def generate_matrix(m, n):
  A = np.random.randint(100, size=(m, n))
  B = np.random.randint(100, size=(m, n))
  return A
```

However, I need to create a function so that I can add two random matrices.
all I have is the starting function and I am just stuck. The thing is the user needs to be able to create the size of each matrix. I have tried to make a code, however all I can muster up is a code where both matrices are identical which is not what I need.

```
def add(A, B):
```

Comment: Did you try `A + B`?

Comment: Did you try to generate the random n and m? This is very simple, is like you didn't even tried anything real.

Comment: yes I have tried that and It does not work, the thing is the user needs to be able to input the values for the size of each matrix.

Comment: Please show us how you call the function and how that didn't work (what were you expecting and what happened). Also note that you are only returning matrix A from the first function.

Comment: I posted it as an answer.

Comment: Assuming that users can input whatever sizes they want, what's the mathematical definition for the sum of two matrices of _different_ sizes? You can't really add matrices if dimensions don't match...

Answer (score 0):

`def generate_matrix(m, n):

  A = np.random.randint(100, size=(m, n))

  B = np.random.randint(100, size=(m, n))

  return A + B`
This is what I have but my formatting is wrong, and it only adds identical length matrices.

Comment: This is not an answer, edit your question to include it into.

Comment: How do you define the addition of 2 matrices that differ in shape?

Answer (score 0):

You have two matrices (which have to be IDENTICAL IN SIZE in order to use summation of matrices).
As long as you have the user define the size (m and n), you're fine.

```
import numpy as np
import random

def generate_matrix(m, n):
    A = np.random.randint(100, size=(m, n))
    return(A)

def user_define(m, n):
    A = generate_matrix(m, n)    
    B = generate_matrix(m, n)
    print("Random Matrix 1 is:")
    print(A)
    print("Random Matrix 2 is:")
    print(B)
    print("Sum of two random matrices is:")
    print(A + B)
    return(A + B)

x = user_define(3, 4)


Random Matrix 1 is:
[[47 24  2 46]
 [65 54  3 80]
 [90  5 42 35]]
Random Matrix 2 is:
[[80 69  8 50]
 [ 2 71 65 36]
 [32  6 49  6]]
Sum of two random matrices is:
[[127  93  10  96]
 [ 67 125  68 116]
 [122  11  91  41]]
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain the Out[12]: part?

Comment: Sorry, the Out[12] part is just there because I'm running it in a Spyder console, and the thing that follows Out[12]: is just the output from the function user_define(3, 4) which is the Sum of two random matrices.

Comment: x = user_define(3, 4)